# Best way to find or match user's contacts to Facebook friends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, facebook, pattern-matching

I have a User, and that User has a bunch of contacts (some contacts have "name" and all have "email").  Contacts have a field for an image_url, and I want to show a picture for that contact.  I want to pull those pictures from Facebook.

Suppose User.first has email "joe@test.com", which is registered with Facebook.

User has_many contacts &&  Contacts belongs_to User.

```
User.first.contacts 
#<Contact id: 1, ctct_name: "Stacy Blah", ctct_email: "stacy.blah@gmail.com", user_id: 1, img_url: nil>, 
#<Contact id: 2, ctct_name: nil, ctct_email: "dick.tracy@gmail.com", user_id: 1, img_url: nil>, 
#<Contact id: 3, ctct_name: "John Doe", ctct_email: "john_doe@gmail.com", user_id: 1, img_url: nil>
```

I have fb_graph working on my site (using Devise :omniauthable).

When User.first connects to Facebook, I have access to their fb token.  So I can do this:

```
facebook_user = FbGraph::User.new('me', :access_token => access_token).fetch
user_friends = facebook_user.friends
```

Now what is the best way to find or match User.first.contacts to user_friends?  **Ideally, I would simply search Facebook connect for emails**, like this:

```
email = Contact.first.ctct_email
search = FbGraph::User.search(email, :access_token => access_token = user['credentials']['token']) 
Contact.first.img_url = search[0].picture # or something like this
```

BUT Facebook API doesn't expose user_friends emails!  So, what can I do?

I've been trying to match based on names, but I run into two problems:  (1) contacts.name may be nil, and (2) user_friends.select {|f| f.name.include?("John Doe")} is too restrictive where the names don't match exactly (e.g., contact.name = "John Doe" but Facebook has this person as "John X. Doe").

I have also tried searching FBGraph::User.search with name parameter = User.first.contacts[2].name.

```
search = FbGraph::User.search("John Doe", :access_token => access_token = user['credentials']['token'])
```

But then I have a severe disambiguation problem -- searching "John Doe" brings up thousands of Facebook users, and they aren't limited to the user_friends!

Surely this is possible.  I've seen services that can pull an image from Facebook for a given contact, with as little information as an email.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for the Facebook user by their email address:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=zuck@fb.com&type=user&access_token=...

Note that as of 12/21/11 there is an [accepted bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266) that this feature currently isn't working.

Comment: That query returns no data.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Interesting - it looks like Facebook has recently killed this functionality.  This used to work as I used this feature many times. If you type Zuck's email address into the search box, it still returns his result so they just disabled the feature for 3rd party developers.    Yet another unannounced breaking change by Facebook.

Comment: It is apparently a bug that is has stopped working: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266